# VBA excel - excel creating empty csv files when using application.ontime

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I got a macro that runs every 30 seconds using Application.Ontime. Every iteration creates a new csv file containing 8 columns and between 50 to 100 rows. The Application.Ontime normally runs from 8am to 5pm.

The problem is that sometimes during the day the macro just stop storing data in the csv files but still creates csv files. Hence, it still creates csv files but without any data in it.

EDIT:

- The files that are created contain headers (StdTenorArray(0))
- The variable StdXXXXXX is defined in another macro (button) and is a global variable

Here is the code:

```
Sub RunOnTime()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set ThisWkb = ThisWorkbook

dTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)
Application.OnTime dTime, "RunOnTime"

Call csvFileArray
Set ThisWkb = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above code calls this macro:

```
Sub csvFileArray()
Dim StdTenorArray(), ArkArr(5) As Variant
Dim FileName As String
Dim StdTenorCnt, h, j As Long
Set ThisWkb = ThisWorkbook
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ArkArr(1) = "XXXXXXctb"
ArkArr(2) = "XXXXXctb"
ArkArr(3) = "XXXXctb"
ArkArr(4) = "XXXctb"
ArkArr(5) = "XXctb"


ReDim StdTenorArray(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(2)).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(3)).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(4)).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(5)).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)


'Standard tenors
StdTenorCnt = 1
If StdXXXXXX = True Then
    For j = 5 To 29
        If UCase(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 4)) = True _
        And WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 10)) = True _
        And WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 11)) = True _
        And IsDate(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 7)) = True _
        And IsDate(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 8)) = True Then

            StdTenorArray(StdTenorCnt) = "" & ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 5) & ";" & Format(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 7), "yyyymmdd") & ";" & Format(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 8), "yyyymmdd") & ";" & ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 9) & ";" & Replace(Format(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 10), "##0.00"), ",", ".") & ";" & Replace(Format(ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 11), "##0.00"), ",", ".") & ";" & ThisWkb.Sheets(ArkArr(1)).Cells(j, 6) & ";JPD"
            StdTenorCnt = StdTenorCnt + 1
        End If
    Next j
End I.

.
.
'more storing in the array like the part above
.
.

StdTenorArray(0) = "Symbol;SpotDate;ValueDate;Removed;Bid;Offer;Tenor;Channel"

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'test
app_path = ThisWkb.Path
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("" & app_path & "\Test\" & Strings.Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & " " & Strings.Format(Now(), "hh.mm.ss") & "." & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer(), "#0.00"), 2) & ".csv", True)



For j = 0 To StdTenorCnt - 1
    a.WriteLine ("" & StdTenorArray(j) & "")
Next j

a.Close
ThisWkb.Sheets("DKK").Cells(1, 27) = "" & Strings.Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss") & ":" & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer(), "#0.00"), 2) & ""
ReDim StdTenorArray(0)
Set fs = Nothing
Set a = Nothing
Set ThisWkb = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Hope someone have a solution to this problem or maybe can point me in the right direction.

Have a nice weekend.

\Kristian

Comment: I have answered your comments in the question. @YowE3K, yes the headers are in the files. StdXXXXX is set in another macro, which is basically a button ON/OFF. It is defined as a public variable.

Comment: It seems macro is called but somehow data is not retrived. I would start with some `log` variable and add into log some message i.e. `log = "StdXXXXX is false"` (in else to if) or `log="No data to store"` at the end of for loop when `StdTenorCnt = 0`. You can then store log variable in output csv if it is not empty to see what happens.

Comment: Is anyone doing anything with the workbook on the occasions when the csv files stop being populated?  That could cause the public variables to lose their values (and thus default to `0`, i.e. `False`) and would lead to your situation.

Comment: As an aside (not related to your problem) ... `Dim StdTenorCnt, h, j As Long` is equivalent to `Dim StdTenorCnt As Variant, h As Variant, j As Long`.  It is not equivalent to `Dim StdTenorCnt As Long, h As Long, j As Long`

Comment: @YowE3K yes, the user is using the workbook while the ontime is running. To resolve that issue i'm now storing the value of the public variables in the workbook. I hope that will solve the issue.